# Rebuild php array structure

Tags: php, arrays, arraylist

I've been looking for the follow solution to create the array structure I need.

For a a list with updates for a specific user who can be following different things, I need to get first the followed items and the data compare to this item. my output for this is as follow.

[array how it is right now](http://pastebin.com/Jex3NWKc)

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [website_id] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [follower_id] => 1
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [follower_id] => 2
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [follower_id] => 3
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [follower_id] => 4
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [follower_id] => 5
                        )
                )
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [website_id] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [follower_id] => 1
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

I want to create the above array like tho on below

[array like it has to be](http://pastebin.com/vqTVTnhi)

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [follower_id] => 1
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [follower_id] => 2
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [follower_id] => 3
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [follower_id] => 4
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [follower_id] => 5
                        )


                    [5] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [follower_id] => 1
                        )
)
```

Thanks in advice.

With kind regards,

Nicky

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me that [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) should be sufficient:

```
$newArray = array_merge($myArray[0]['website_id'], $myArray[1]['website_id']);
```

Comment: Sometimes it has to merge 2 arrays like the example, but it can also be that it has to merge 5 arrays how about that?

Comment: @Nicky `array_merge()` can take any number of arrays: `$newArray = array_merge($myArray[0]['website_id'], $myArray[1]['website_id'], $myArray[2]['website_id'], $myArray[3]['website_id']);` ...

Comment: I understand but I can't write this by hand, it's variable. sometimes 2 arrays, sometimes 4 or more.

Comment: Then you need to iterate: `$newArray = array(); for ($i = 0, $j = count($myArray); $i < $j; $i++) { $newArray = array_merge($newArray, $myArray[$i]['website_id']); }` (untested)

Comment: You're my hero! Thank u very much! :)